# Reference two portable classes on UWP project after creators update

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-core

Hello lovely people of SO. Recently I got the creators update and the problems with it. Today I started developing new UWP application and hit a rock.

I created a class library project (Class Library (Universal Windows)) as usual, added some models in it and then suddenly I discovered that I cannot add a reference from my UWP project to the class library project(Unable to add reference...).

I read somewhere that after creators update you can only reference portable libraries... Fine I said and I created a portable class library. I managed to reference Class library to UWP but then another problem occured. I discovered that I cannot add reference between two portable class libraries. I get an error which says that they target two different platforms and I can change it on project properties. The problem is that the two libraries point to the exact same Target Framework. Did anyone find a way out of this mess? I simply want to create a UWP application with 2 class libraries and reference them like:

UWP -> Class Library1 -> Class Library2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please invest a few seconds when writing a question and add paragraphs. This huge block of text makes it hard to read your question. Also in how much in your question related to asp.net core in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about the paragraphs. I also changed the tag to .net-core which my UWP project targets.

Comment: Have a look at .net standard, Microsoft is moving towards that and leaving "PCL behind" Check this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/. I haven't try pcl with UWP, maybe isn't compatible or maybe you have different profiles on your PCL projects. Open the CSPROJ files and check if both have same profile.

Comment: @user1845593 Thank you. The link you provided really helped. I created .NET Standart library and managed to reference all projects.